# Redirecting to the resource file in static directory with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a static directory that contains some resources (data files), and I can access the files directly: i.e., `http://hello.com/static/dir/abc.pdf`. However, I got error with the directory as the address: i.e., `http://hello.com/static/dir`.

Using flask, I can solve this issue by showing the contents of the directory.

```
@app.route('/static/<path:url>') @protect 
def show(url):
    content_dir = app.config['CONTENT_DIR']
    directory = "%s/%s/box/%s" % (content_dir, url, url2)
    result = []

    if os.path.isdir(directory):
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            content['url'] = '/static/...
        result.append(content)
    return render_template("box.html",...)
```

The issue is that with this route processing, the direct file accessing doesn't work any more as `http://hello.com/static/dir/abc.pdf` always triggers the `show()` method.

How can I redirect to the resource file (abc.pdf in the example), without being redirected to the `show()` method?

Comment: You could check if `url` ends with a file extension.

Comment: Ideally you won't be using the development server in production. You should let your http server worry about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom static route, check if the path is a file or a directory.  If it's a file, serve it, otherwise show the directory index.

```
import os
from flask import send_file

path = os.path.join(app.config['CONTENT_DIR'], url, 'box', url2)

if os.path.isfile(path):
    return send_file(path)

return render_template('box.html', ...)
```

Of course, since the path is specified by the url sent by the user, you should check that it's safe first.